# how exception finds correct catch block

Tags: java, exception

I was wondering how catch block works.

I have below code,

```
catch(ArithmeticException e){
    System.out.println("task1 is completed");
}  
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    System.out.println("task 2 completed");
}  
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("common task completed");
}
```

If divide by zero occurs it will go to Arithmetic Exception and skips rest.

How is it internally implemented so that it is going into the correct catch block?

Comment: Too broad, and in any case it isn't actually specified.

Comment: Are you actually interested in the physical implementation of this, or are you interested in the exact rule that decides which block to choose?

Comment: http://www.artima.com/underthehood/exceptions.html

Comment: @EJP - my experience here shows that when the person asking is not a native English speaker, such phrases can become ambiguous. Let the OP settle this.

Comment: @RealSkeptic There is nothing ambiguous about 'internally implemented'. My experience here, and on the Internet since 1990, and the Usenet before that, is that  that you should answer the question that is actually asked, and that you should not jump to conclusions about the person asking.

Comment: @EJP: Well, with Java "internally implemented" can reasonably be read as "what bytecode is generated for this code and how does that bytecode work". That part is covered by the language and JVM specs.

Comment: @Thilo I agree. What I'm arguing against is the notion that there is any ambiguity here as between 'how it is intermally implemented' and 'the exact [language] rule that decides which block to choose', which the OP clearly already knows, as he has correctly identified the `catch` block that should be executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "implemented" you mean "what is the bytecode generated for this", that part is of course covered by the language specification, and there is [a good article](http://www.artima.com/underthehood/exceptions.html) about it.

Basically, every code segment (method) can have an associated exception table. In this table, you have an entry for every catch block, that specifies which lines of code are covered by it (the extent of the `try` block), what exception is being caught, and where to jump to handle it (the `catch` block).

When an exception is raised, the JVM goes through this table from top to bottom and continues execution in the first catch block that matches.

If it does not find one, it exits the current method and looks in the exception table of the caller (the exception bubbles up the call stack until someone deals with it).

Comment: Thank you for the article you provided. It is really useful. Do you have any other article wrt Exception table? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It does not directly go to the matching catch block...

But it linearly searches each catch block to find the required exception, if it finds then it skips rest of the catch block... Thats All.

Answer (score 0):

The first matching catch block is executed.
For more details see here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Its not much of going to a specific block. In your try block an exception can and normally is "thrown" your catch block merely anticipates the exception and "catches" it preventing the program from crashing.

Answer (score -1):

` **Java has a built-in mechanism for handling runtime errors, referred to as exception handling. This is to ensure that you can write robust programs for mission-critical applications.**

Older programming languages such as C have some drawbacks in exception handing. For example, suppose the programmer wishes to open a file for processing:

1.The programmers are not made to aware of the exceptional conditions. For example, the file to be opened may not necessarily exist. The programmer therefore did not write codes to test whether the file exists before opening the file.

2.Suppose the programmer is aware of the exceptional conditions, he/she might decide to finish the main logic first, and write the exception handling codes later – this "later", unfortunately, usually never happens. In other words, you are not force to write the exception handling codes together with the main logic.

3.Suppose the programmer decided to write the exception handling codes, the exception handling codes intertwine with the main logic in many if-else statements. This makes main logic hard to follow and the entire program hard to read. For example,

if (file exists) 
{

open file;

while (there is more records to be processed) {

```
  if (no IO errors) {
     process the file record
  } else {
     handle the errors
  }
```

}
   if (file is opened) close the file;
} else {``
   report the file does not exist;
}

`